# There is already an object named ##ObjectName

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure in which i create a table if the table does not exist at that moment in the code (tried select top 0 * from other table first but the outcome is the same).

That table will be used for inserting data into it with different selections, but it can be the case that the first selection will not be made because there is no data for that specific selection.

Because of that my idea was quite simple to just create it if it doesnt exists with the code for each selection.

But when i try run it i get:

> There is already an object named '##TOTAL_SELECTION' in the database.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or how I can work around this?
It looks very logical like this to me because the table only gets created if it doesn't exist.

```
 IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEMPDB.SYS.OBJECTS WHERE NAME = '##TOTAL_SELECTION' AND TYPE = 'U' ) = 0
    BEGIN
         CREATE TABLE ##TOTAL_SELECTION (ID NUMERIC(14,0), TYPE VARCHAR(100)  )
    END    

    --INSERT DATA INTO THE TABLE

    /* SOME OTHER CODE */

     IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEMPDB.SYS.OBJECTS WHERE NAME = '##TOTAL_SELECTION' AND TYPE = 'U' ) = 0
    BEGIN
         CREATE TABLE ##TOTAL_SELECTION (ID NUMERIC(14,0), TYPE VARCHAR(100)  )
    END    

    --INSERT DATA INTO THE TABLE

    /* SOME moreCODE */
```

Comment: Not the source of your problem, but please use `if exists (...)` instead of `if (select count) > 0`.

Comment: This is a compile time issue. SQL Server will only allow one `CREATE TABLE` for the same temp table. Why do you need the second one anyway? You've already ensured it was created above

Comment: Not related, but you can save yourself a lot of typing by using `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TOTAL_SELECTION ' , 'U') IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: It isnt sure that it is created the first time, because that is in a bigger IF block as well. And it is beforehand not sure which IF parts will be done so i created the table (with IF....) in each block.

Comment: So can you just move the whole creation to the beginning of the proc so it is guaranteed to run once and it just contains one attempt to `CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: Also...be careful here. You are using global temp tables which are almost always not needed. Just a temp table is usually adequate. Global temp tables have some serious challenges that often get overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the table again to insert another data, you can also do truncation like:

```
  --This will remove all the content of your table. 
  truncate table ##TOTAL_SELECTION
```

instead of trying to recreate it, as you cannot create a table (even though it is temporary) multiple times with the same name. You can try to trick it by adding numbers in the name of the temp tables (##Total_Selection1, ##Total_Selection2 etc.)

Also, please use the condition below instead of `select count(*) ... = 0`:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TOTAL_SELECTION ' , 'U') IS NOT NULL
   drop TABLE ##TOTAL_SELECTION
```

Comment: @MartinSmith Can u please explain why it does not work?

Comment: SQL Server can't compile a plan for a batch with multiple `CREATE TABLE #foo`  regardless if the table already exists or not or if they are in `IF` statements

Comment: @MartinSmith I got it, you are right. Maybe instead of trying to recreate an existing temp table, he can consider truncating. I have updated my answer. Thanks.